# Re-link my Firebase account with my old Google Cloud Billing?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-billing

I already have Google Cloud Billing for my Firebase account, but sometimes when the budget is greater than the quota, my Firebase plan gets terminated. Whenever I try to link my Firebase account back to that Google Cloud Billing, I can't, and I need to re-create a new Google Cloud Billing. Is there a way to re-link my Firebase account with my old Google Cloud billing? Do I have to create a new bill?

Comment: Which Firebase Plan you were in when the budget exceeded quota?

Comment: it was blaze, now its back to spark. i can't go back to my old blaze billing for some reason.

Comment: I think you were in Free Trial Credit Billing account and as soon as your free trial credit got expired, all the projects attached to the Free Trial Billing Account had automatically been downgraded to Free (Spark) plan. This was done to prevent any surprise charges on your Billing Account.  Changing the projects billing plan to Blaze is the same action as 'changing the billing setting to make the project be a part of billing account 'and changing the projects billing plan to Spark is the same action as 'removing the billing account to the project'

Comment: May you do not have enough permissions like billing admin permission/owner on the old billing account (just a guess) to link your firebase account back to Google Cloud billing. You can contact [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) for a detailed response and explanation.

Comment: Did you try contacting Firebase support for your issue or was it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I think you were in Free Trial Credit Billing account and as soon as your free trial credit got expired, all the projects attached to the Free Trial Billing Account had automatically been downgraded to Free (Spark) plan. This was done to prevent any surprise charges on your Billing Account. Changing the projects billing plan to Blaze is the same action as 'changing the billing setting to make the project be a part of billing account 'and changing the projects billing plan to Spark is the same action as 'removing the billing account to the project'.

May you do not have enough permissions like billing admin permission/owner on the old billing account (just a guess) to link your firebase account back to Google Cloud billing. You can contact [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) for a detailed response and explanation.